# Python how i can parse list?

Tags: python, django

**How i can parse it?**

```
    check = request.POST.getlist('check')

    print(check)

    [u'["1","2"]']
```

send ajax JSON data to server

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+json

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to decode it from JSON sent from the browser. You can do encode or decode like this:

```
import json

# to encode a list to json
json.dumps(yourlist)

# to decode it from json
json.loads(yourjson)
```

Reference: [The Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Answer (score -3):

In your list, you have received a string. To parse through this look-alike list, you will have to go through the individual characters.
Here is an example:

```
list = [u'["1","2"]']

for i in range(len(list[0])):
    print list[0][i]
```

Output:

```
[
"
1
"
,
"
2
"
]
```

You can parse through this by starting at `list[0][2]` and incrementing by 4.

Comment: Why go to the work of iterating over the list by index? A much more Pythonic way would be to simply iterate over the list by value: `for el in list[0]`. Also, one should note that it is general not a good idea to overwrite builtin names.